# How to find NextScheduledTaskTime of a scheduled task?

Tags: programming

Prior to 11.2 there was a function `NextScheduledTaskTime` which does what it says on the packet but only for cloud objects and not local scheduled task objects.

What is the best way to determine the next scheduled task time for a local scheduled task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The undocumented function `` Internal`NextScheduledTaskTime `` appears to do the job for local tasks:

```
$t = CreateScheduledTask[Print["hi"], 5]

NextScheduledTaskTime[$t]
(* ...unevaluated... *)

Internal`NextScheduledTaskTime[$t]
(* Infinity *)

StartScheduledTask[$t]

Internal`NextScheduledTaskTime[$t]
(* 4.0922000 *)

Internal`NextScheduledTaskTime[$t]
(* 2.0207600 *)

(* in the message window... *)
(* "hi" *)

Internal`NextScheduledTaskTime[$t]
(* 4.0646800 *)

StopScheduledTask[$t]

Internal`NextScheduledTaskTime[$t]
(* Infinity *)
```

Comment: Perfect! How did you find this function?

Comment: A search like ``Names["**`*ScheduledTask*", IgnoreCase->True] // Sort // Column`` is often my first stop on a spelunking expedition.  It came up lucky this time.